# JavaScript CSV Export - Adding tab after each value

Tags: javascript

This is only happening in Chrome and only started happening after updating to version 70.0.3538.77. This never happened in Chrome prior to updating.

I have some JavaScript that is activated when a button is clicked to export a table to a .csv file.

Each cell in the file has a tab (or maybe line break?) after the value. Anyone know what might be going on here?

Here is the code to export:

```
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV file
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();
}

function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr,table thead tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td,th");

        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename+(new Date().getTime())+".csv");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy fix would be to trim the value of the cell:

```
row.push(cols[j].innerText.trim());
```

`trim()` removes all leading or trailing line endings, tabs, spaces, etc. from the value.

You may also want to think about qualifying your text with quotations to prevent issues with commas in your cell values:

```
row.push('"' + cols[j].innerText.trim() + '"');
```

There are definitely more complicated cases (what if your value contains a quotation now?), so you may need to build on this over time to output a proper CSV file.